# Create a list based on pattern in string vector

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate a list with information by location. Currently, I have a character vector with strings. Which has location, information, information, information, location2, information, information, information structure. I want a list where each element is location1: information, information information etc.

I have tried to create a loop that identifies the locations in the data, however i fail to understand how to dynamically join the information together with the location (the locations and # of information is changing so I need the solution to be dynamic).

```
list_of_locations = list()
locations = c("location1","location2")
original_vector = c("location1","July 123","August 345", "September 678", "location2","July 123","August 345")

for (word in original_vector){
  if(word %in% locations){
    list_of_locations[[word]] = word 
  } else {
    list_of_locations[[word]] = word
  }
}
```

I'm looking for a list:

```
1: location1, July 123, August 345, September 678
2: location2, July 123, August 345...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a useful data format, but here you are:

```
split(original_vector, 
  cumsum(
    grepl("location", original_vector, fixed = TRUE) #search for the word "location"
  )
)
#$`1`
#[1] "location1"     "July 123"      "August 345"    "September 678"
#
#$`2`
#[1] "location2"  "July 123"   "August 345"
```

Or (thanks to @Ronak) if you have the locations vector:

```
split(original_vector, cumsum(original_vector %in% locations)
```

If your data were actually in the described format (1 location, 3 information entries), I would turn `original_vector` into a matrix:

```
original_vector = c("location1","July 123","August 345", "September 678", "location2","July 123","August 345", "September 678")
t(matrix(original_vector, 4))
#     [,1]        [,2]       [,3]         [,4]           
#[1,] "location1" "July 123" "August 345" "September 678"
#[2,] "location2" "July 123" "August 345" "September 678"
```

This format allows easy subsetting and other data processing.

Comment: True that works on the sample data i provided here, but the fact is that the locations data captured in the "locations" vector above has different names (i.e. New York, Los Angeles, Newark etc.). Should have been more specific on this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This solves my issue.